# Constructing jQuery object and getting its parent from an array of objects

Tags: jquery

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

booArray is an array of objects named: prefix_someName, where someName varies from one object to another.

Those objects are respectively associated with their div elements, the id's of those divs would be someName, i.e. `prefix_monkey` object would be associated with `#monkey` div.

In this code I need to continuously apply a method to the objects themselves but stop doing so when their corresponding div completes its transition. I'm trying to construct the div id from a string extracted from the object itself in the `var foo` (iddoc is where the string is stored), make that into a jQ object and then get its parent as that happens to be the element doing the transition in this case. (some foo's will be doing transitioning themselves, so no need to reach out for parent)

...not sure in how many places I messed up this code... Any help appreciated

```
$(booArray).each(function() {

       var foo = '$(\'#' + $(this).attr('iddoc') + '\')';

       var bla = setInterval(function() {
           console.log('transition in progress');
       },10);

       foo.parent().one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
           console.log(foo.parent().attr('id') + ': transition completed');
           clearInterval(bla);
       });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you constructing a string of jQuery code instead of just constructing a selector to access the object?

```
var foo = '$(\'#' + $(this).attr('iddoc') + '\')';
```

should be

```
var foo = $('#' + $(this).attr('iddoc'));
```

Comment: yes, that's one of those places that needed work. Thanks. I was just trying to make it happen... being the answer to your question

Comment: did it fix the problem? sorry I don't know why I phrased my response as a question..

Comment: it accepts the foo object, yes so in that sense it was a correct tip, thank you. This code seems to have holes elsewhere though. Could be beyond scope of this question. I'll update if there's progress